# How to add space between rows and columns in ttk treeview?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I want to increase the row size and decrease column size so my icons have are displayed properly:
[image]

The padding option pads the entire treeview and there is no height or width option for columns. I tried with
`ttk.Style().configure("MyStyle.Treeview", rowheight=36)` and it doesn't seem to do anything and I can't find any helpful documentation about ttk.Style *anywhere*. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] in your question.

Comment: Did you add `style="MyStyle.Treeview"` when creating the `Treeview` widget?